# SSRS 2012 where and how to download

Tags: reporting-services

I need SSRS for SQL Server 2012 however I cannot find it anywhere can somebody help and share links?

I found one but its required Sharepoint on my machine.

I need it for learning purpose that way I don't have share point.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have three different versions of SQL Server to get it.  It is an add on to SQL Server.  Either:

SQL Server Enterprise Edition

SQL Server Developer Edition

SQL Server with Advanced Services (SSIS, SSAS, SSRS)

The third option is free and is here I believe: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Ensure you select the larger sized one.  During install ensure you select 'Business Intelligence Development Studio' or 'SQL Server Data Tools' (I know they renamed it under the 'All Programs' Menu for God knows what reason except to be further confusing to an already confusing product.  Just select all check boxes if you can to be sure you get it during an install.

To ensure you have it, it is basically an add on to Visual Studio 2010 called 'SQL Server Data Tools' under All Programs but once you are in Visual Studio it is still called 'Business Intelligence Development Studio'.  You can get to it from All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 > SQL Server Data Tools.

You need to ensure you also have a working SSRS Server to host reports too so ensure you can get to 'All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 > Configuration Tools > Reporting Services Configuration Manager' as well if you are going to learn SSRS you might as well learn the advantages of publishing the reports as well where the real power of SSRS comes in.

Comment: UPDATE TO THIS SOLUTION: I was not aware but you can get an update to develop SSRS 2012 in VS 2012 as well.  I am not certain though if this is bundled with all SQL Server 2012 installs as the ones I have as of mid summer did not have it.  But if you want to ditch 2010 and just be on 2012 or 2013 then you can add it on as well: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the media to make an installation you should mark `BIDS (Business Inteligence Developer Studio)` to be installed.

You could read this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174597(v=sql.105).aspx

Of course, change the webpage's language before so you can understand the article