# How to Get SQL Server Reporting Services to Install so that it Works

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I found this link for SQL Server Reporting Services

[SQL Server Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/675671ca-e6c9-48a2-82e9-386778f3a49f)

In this they said go to SQL Server data tools and when I search I can't find so what I do for that?

And when I try to do that when I go to configuration tools in SQL Server 2008 R2 and click on 
Reporting Services configuration manager then it show me error when I connect it show me error

> Unable to connect to the Report Server HOME-PC

So here anybody can tell me how do I start using SQL Server Reporting Services?

Answer (score 1):

You did not install SSRS correctly I am guessing as parts are missing.  You can install SSRS through the SQL Server insall in a few different versions:

[SSRS 2012 where and how to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057820/ssrs-2012-where-and-how-to-download/19061446#19061446)

The download for Express(the free version) is here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Once you get a successful install there is a more SSRS centric tool than the services configuration.  It is under All Programs>SQL Server (version)>Configuration Tools>Reporting Services Configuration Manager.  You need to ensure that SSRS is fully working before developing for it.  I wrote an article on deployment here that covers the bases:

[How SSRS deployment works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105007/how-ssrs-deployment-works/18113853#18113853)

Checking that SSRS is actually up and working with correct permissions is half the fun of SSRS! ;)

Comment: i have sql server 2008 r2

Comment: when i install like start.—->all prgrams—->Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2—–>Configuration Tools——->Sql Server Installation Center then i select New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation but when i choose and select any folder or disk like program files or Disk C then it shows me error Invalid Folder ,…how i solve this issue

Comment: You probably don't have access to the location for the user as the admin of the install.  Ensure you are logged in as the admin you are going to use for SQL server.  Ensure you can get to the folder location you want to install SQL Server to as that user and create/edit/destroy files/folders at that location.

Comment: here i find folder because i have folder in program files-Microsoft sql server

Comment: Right but can you access that location as the default admin and DELETE/ADD files to it?  If you can then it is not user permissions but something dealing with the service not finding the path.  You may always try to create a folder closer to the root like 'C:\SQLServer' and give it required permissions.

Comment: I suggested creating it to deal with permissions on existing locations, not that it was there already.